# python regular expression irregularity

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I don't understand the next behavior of python regular expression. I have the next code :

```
IPRegExp = re.compile('[0..9a..f]+\:\s+\w\w\s\w\w\s\w\w\s\w\w')
...some code...
for line in dmpLines:
...some code ...
    if IPRegExp.findall(line):
        print something
```

- when `line = "410000: 2c 83 00 03  and. r4,#0x3,r3"` **I get the print but**
- when `line = "410004: fc 89 30 00  add r4,r6,r9"` **it doesn't print**

when I change the regular expression to

```
IPRegExp = re.compile('[0123456789abcdef]+\:\s+\w\w\s\w\w\s\w\w\s\w\w')
```

I get both prints.

what is missing ? using centos6 and python 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood how character classes work. The correct way to spell a sequence of characters to match is a `-` dash between two characters, so `0-9` and `a-f`, not `..`.

Use this:

```
re.compile('[0-9a-f]+\:\s+\w\w\s\w\w\s\w\w\s\w\w')
```

Your version, using `[0..9a..f]` matches only the characters `0`, `.`, `9`, `a` and `f`. Your second line ends with `4` before the `:` and that isn't part of that set of characters.

Note the difference between the two returned matches here:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('[0..9a..f]+\:\s+\w\w\s\w\w\s\w\w\s\w\w', '410000: 2c 83 00 03  and. r4,#0x3,r3')
['0000: 2c 83 00 03']
>>> re.findall('[0-9a-f]+\:\s+\w\w\s\w\w\s\w\w\s\w\w', '410000: 2c 83 00 03  and. r4,#0x3,r3')
['410000: 2c 83 00 03']
```

Your version fails to include the `41` at the start as `4` and `1` are not part of the character class.

Comment: @yehudahs: because the pattern `0000:` matches; the 4 `0` characters fit the pattern.

Comment: @yehudahs: `123456780:` would have matched on the last `0` before the `:`, for example, even though the `12345678` at the start doesn't. You didn't use an anchor in your pattern so it doesn't have to match at the start of the string, nor did you give it a minimum number of hex characters to match, other than 'at least one'.

Comment: and also "..". thax again for the comment with the 123456780 - will take it into account to avoid more errors.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the right notation. If you want to use a range use '-' instead of '..'

```
regex = r'[0-9a-f]+\:\s+\w\w\s\w\w\s\w\w\s\w\w'
```